# Ubuntu issue with external HDDs unmounting

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, docker

I'm running into an issue with my media server running Ubuntu 22.04.2. I'm running Plex in a docker container with a few other containers on the server. I have two HDDs that stay permanently connected to the server at all times. I've edited my /etc/fstab with UUID mounting points for both HDDs.

What I'm finding is that after a reboot of the server, everything is mounted normally and works as expected, but at some random point after reboot, one of my HDDs has unmounted and the files on it are inaccessible. If I check the list of disks, this drive has now moved from /dev/sda to /dev/sdc during runtime.

I've just tried 'mount -a' and it remounts as normal and then restarting the container gets the files accessible again but this is concerning, as nothing has touched the server and this is happening randomly on it's own a couple times now.

What would cause a mounted and working HDD to unmount itself and reattach as a new /dev/sdX drive without physically touching the drive? And on top of that, if this is potentially some sort of failure physically in my drive, what can be done to potentially detect this and remount and restart the containers when it does happen?

Comment: Look at the logs. `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sd`